# Understand how to use StateNotifier and StateNotifierProvider in ConsumerState class

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I am making progress but it is slow. I need to update the state of a StateNotifierProvider by using the StateNotifier class but I don't seem to be getting it.

I have a model/Notifier class here:

```
class Globals {
  final String? currentUid;
  final String? currentUEmail;
  final String? userDocumentId;
  final String? companyId;
  final String? mlsId;
  final String? currentTrxnId;
  final String? currentCompanyName;
  final String? currentCompanyState;
  final String? currentUserId;
  final String? currentUserState;
  final String? currentUserName;
  final String? selectedState;
  final String? selectedUserState;
  final String? selectedTrxnState;
  final String? selectedCompany;
  final String? selectedUser;
  final String? targetScreen;
  final bool? newEvent;
  final bool? newTrxn;
  final bool? newUser;
  final bool? newCompany;

  Globals(
      {this.currentUid,
      this.currentUEmail,
      this.userDocumentId,
      this.companyId,
      this.mlsId,
      this.currentTrxnId,
      this.currentCompanyName,
      this.currentCompanyState,
      this.currentUserId,
      this.currentUserState,
      this.currentUserName,
      this.selectedState,
      this.selectedUserState,
      this.selectedTrxnState,
      this.selectedCompany,
      this.selectedUser,
      this.targetScreen,
      this.newEvent,
      this.newTrxn,
      this.newUser,
      this.newCompany});

  Globals copyWith({
    String? currentUid,
    String? currentUEmail,
    String? userDocumentId,
    String? companyId,
    String? mlsId,
    String? currentTrxnId,
    String? currentCompanyName,
    String? currentCompanyState,
    String? currentUserId,
    String? currentUserState,
    String? currentUserName,
    String? selectedState,
    String? selectedUserState,
    String? selectedTrxnState,
    String? selectedCompany,
    String? selectedUser,
    String? targetScreen,
    bool? newEvent,
    bool? newTrxn,
    bool? newUser,
    bool? newCompany,
  }) {
    return Globals(
      currentUid: currentUid ?? this.currentUid,
      currentUEmail: currentUEmail ?? this.currentUEmail,
      userDocumentId: userDocumentId ?? this.userDocumentId,
      companyId: companyId ?? this.companyId,
      mlsId: mlsId ?? this.mlsId,
      currentTrxnId: currentTrxnId ?? this.currentTrxnId,
      currentCompanyName: currentCompanyName ?? this.currentCompanyName,
      currentCompanyState: currentCompanyState ?? this.currentCompanyState,
      currentUserId: currentUserId ?? this.currentUserId,
      currentUserState: currentUserState ?? this.currentUserState,
      currentUserName: currentUserName ?? this.currentUserName,
      selectedState: selectedState ?? this.selectedState,
      selectedUserState: selectedUserState ?? this.selectedUserState,
      selectedTrxnState: selectedTrxnState ?? this.selectedTrxnState,
      selectedCompany: selectedCompany ?? this.selectedCompany,
      selectedUser: selectedUser ?? this.selectedUser,
      targetScreen: targetScreen ?? this.targetScreen,
      newEvent: newEvent ?? this.newEvent,
      newTrxn: newTrxn ?? this.newTrxn,
      newUser: newUser ?? this.newUser,
      newCompany: newCompany ?? this.newCompany,
    );
  }
}

class GlobalsNotifier extends StateNotifier<Globals> {
  GlobalsNotifier(super.state); //  constructor

  // functions to update class members
  void updatecurrentUid(String newcurrentUid) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentUid: newcurrentUid);
  }

  void updatecurrentUEmail(String newcurrentUEmail) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentUEmail: newcurrentUEmail);
  }

  void updateuserDocumentId(String newuserDocumentId) {
    state = state.copyWith(userDocumentId: newuserDocumentId);
  }

  void updatecompanyId(String newcompanyId) {
    state = state.copyWith(companyId: newcompanyId);
  }

  void updatemlsId(String newmlsId) {
    state = state.copyWith(mlsId: newmlsId);
  }

  void updatecurrentTrxnId(String newcurrentTrxnId) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentTrxnId: newcurrentTrxnId);
  }

  void updatecurrentCompanyName(String newcurrentCompanyName) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentCompanyName: newcurrentCompanyName);
  }

  void updatecurrentUserId(String newcurrentUserId) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentUserId: newcurrentUserId);
  }

  void updatecurrentUserState(String newcurrentUserState) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentUserState: newcurrentUserState);
  }

  void updatecurrentUserName(String newcurrentUserName) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentUserName: newcurrentUserName);
  }

  void updateselectedState(String newselectedState) {
    state = state.copyWith(selectedState: newselectedState);
  }

  void updateselectedUserState(String newselectedUserState) {
    state = state.copyWith(selectedUserState: newselectedUserState);
  }

  void updateselectedTrxnState(String newselectedTrxnState) {
    state = state.copyWith(selectedTrxnState: newselectedTrxnState);
  }

  void updateselectedCompany(String newselectedCompany) {
    state = state.copyWith(selectedCompany: newselectedCompany);
  }

  void updateselectedUser(String newselectedUser) {
    state = state.copyWith(selectedUser: newselectedUser);
  }

  void updatetargetScreen(String newtargetScreen) {
    state = state.copyWith(targetScreen: newtargetScreen);
  }

  void updatenewEvent(bool newNewEvent) {
    state = state.copyWith(newEvent: newNewEvent);
  }

  void updatenewTrxn(bool newNewTrxn) {
    state = state.copyWith(newTrxn: newNewTrxn);
  }

  void updatenewUser(bool newNewUser) {
    state = state.copyWith(newUser: newNewUser);
  }

  void updatenewCompany(bool newNewCompany) {
    state = state.copyWith(newCompany: newNewCompany);
  }
}
```

I have created a ConsumerStatefulWidget with a ConsumerState class here:

```
// Create the global provider
final globalProvider = StateNotifierProvider<GlobalsNotifier, Globals>(
    (ref) => GlobalsNotifier(Globals(
        currentUid: '',
        currentUEmail: '',
        userDocumentId: '',
        companyId: '',
        mlsId: '',
        currentTrxnId: '',
        currentCompanyName: '',
        currentCompanyState: '',
        currentUserId: '',
        currentUserName: '',
        currentUserState: '',
        selectedCompany: '',
        selectedState: '',
        selectedTrxnState: '',
        selectedUser: '',
        selectedUserState: '',
        targetScreen: '',
        newCompany: true,
        newEvent: true,
        newTrxn: true,
        newUser: true)));

class LoginScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'login_screen';

  @override
  ConsumerState<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends ConsumerState<LoginScreen> {
  bool showSpinner = false;
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    ref.read(globalProvider.notifier); // gives access to ref
    super.initState();
  }

  late String email;
  late String password;

  getCurrentAgencyName() async {
    final globals = ref.watch(globalProvider);
    final DocumentSnapshot _currentAgentProfile =
        await agentsRef.doc(globals.currentUid).get();

    if (_currentAgentProfile != null) {
      ref.read(globals.notifier).updatecompanyId(_currentAgentProfile.get('agencyId'));
      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUserStateProvider.notifier).state =
          _currentAgentProfile.get('state');
      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.mlsId.notifier).state =
          _currentAgentProfile.get('mlsId');
    }

    final DocumentSnapshot _currentAgencyProfile =
        await agencyRef.doc(ref.watch(GlobalsProvider.companyId)).get();

    if (_currentAgencyProfile != null) {
      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentCompanyState.notifier).state =
          _currentAgencyProfile.get('state');
      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentCompanyName.notifier).state =
          _currentAgencyProfile.get('name');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool loginFail = false;
    String errorMessage = "";
    final globalVars = ref.watch(globalProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          // children: [
          //   Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',
          //       fit: BoxFit.cover, height: 56),
          // ],
        ),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, // This fixes the keyboard white space
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text(
                'Login',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  fontSize: 40.0,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 48.0,
              ),
              TextField(
                autofocus: true,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  email = value;
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Email',
                  errorText: loginFail ? 'incorrect email' : null,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8.0,
              ),
              TextField(
                obscureText: true,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  password = value;
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Password',
                  errorText: loginFail ? 'incorrect passwowrd' : null,
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: const Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                ),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ResetPasswordScreen())),
              ),
              TextButton(
                  child: const Text(
                    'Forgot Password',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    setState(() {
                      showSpinner = true;
                    });
                    try {
                      UserCredential userCredential =
                          await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                              email: email, password: password);

                      if (userCredential != null) {
                        // Set the global state
                        globalVars.updatecurrentUId(currentUId: _auth.currentUser!.uid);
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUid.notifier).state =
                            _auth.currentUser!.uid;
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUserId.notifier).state =
                            _auth.currentUser!.uid;
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUEmail.notifier).state =
                            _auth.currentUser!.email;
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.targetScreen.notifier).state =
                            0;
                        await getCurrentAgencyName();
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()),
                        );
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          loginFail = true;
                        });
                      }
                      setState(() {
                        showSpinner = false;
                      });
                    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
                      switch (error.code) {
                        case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
                        case "invalid-email":
                          errorMessage =
                              "Your email address appears to be malformed.";
                          break;
                        case "email-already-in-use":
                          errorMessage = "Email is already in use.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
                        case "wrong-password":
                          errorMessage = "Your password is wrong.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
                        case "user-not-found":
                          errorMessage = "User with this email doesn't exist.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_USER_DISABLED":
                        case "user-disabled":
                          errorMessage =
                              "User with this email has been disabled.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS":
                        case "too-many-requests":
                          errorMessage = "Too many requests. Try again later.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
                        case "operation-not-allowed":
                          errorMessage =
                              "Signing in with Email and Password is not enabled.";
                          break;
                        default:
                          errorMessage =
                              "An undefined Error happened. Please try again.";
                      }

                      if (errorMessage != null && errorMessage != "") {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            (SnackBar(content: Text(errorMessage))));
                      }
                    }
                  }),
              RoundedButton(
                  title: 'Log In',
                  colour: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  onPressed: () async {
                    setState(() {
                      showSpinner = true;
                    });
                    try {
                      UserCredential userCredential =
                          await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                              email: email, password: password);

                      if (userCredential != null) {
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUid.notifier).state =
                            _auth.currentUser!.uid;
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUserId.notifier).state =
                            _auth.currentUser!.uid;
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUEmail.notifier).state =
                            _auth.currentUser!.email;
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.targetScreen.notifier).state =
                            0;
                        await getCurrentAgencyName();
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()),
                        );
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          loginFail = true;
                        });
                      }
                      setState(() {
                        showSpinner = false;
                      });
                    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
                      switch (error.code) {
                        case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
                        case "invalid-email":
                          errorMessage =
                              "Your email address appears to be malformed.";
                          break;
                        case "email-already-in-use":
                          errorMessage = "Email is already in use.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
                        case "wrong-password":
                          errorMessage = "Your password is wrong.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
                        case "user-not-found":
                          errorMessage = "User with this email doesn't exist.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_USER_DISABLED":
                        case "user-disabled":
                          errorMessage =
                              "User with this email has been disabled.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS":
                        case "too-many-requests":
                          errorMessage = "Too many requests. Try again later.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
                        case "operation-not-allowed":
                          errorMessage =
                              "Signing in with Email and Password is not enabled.";
                          break;
                        default:
                          errorMessage =
                              "An undefined Error happened. Please try again.";
                      }

                      if (errorMessage != null && errorMessage != "") {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            (SnackBar(content: Text(errorMessage))));
                      }
                    }
                  }),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 100.0,
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: const Text(
                  'New User?  Create Account',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.blue),
                ),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => UserRegisterScreen())),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have created a StateNotifier called globalProvider which I thought would give me access to the StateNotifier functions so I could update the state.

In the function getCurrentAgencyName I am trying to use a couple different ways to update state but I have errors.

```
  globals.updatecompanyId(_currentAgentProfile.get('agencyId'));
  ref.read(globals.notifier).updatecompanyId(_currentAgentProfile.get('agencyId'));
```

The error for the first line is this: **The method 'updatecompanyId' isn't defined for the type 'Globals'.**
The error for the second line is this: **The getter 'notifier' isn't defined for the type 'Globals'.**

I think this is telling me I don't have globals defined correctly or I am not using it in the right way.

```
getCurrentAgencyName() async {
    final globals = ref.watch(globalProvider);  <<<<  globals declared

    if (_currentAgentProfile != null) {
      globals.updatecompanyId(_currentAgentProfile.get('agencyId'));
      ref.read(globals.notifier).updatecompanyId(_currentAgentProfile.get('agencyId'));
      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUserStateProvider.notifier).state =
          _currentAgentProfile.get('state');
      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.mlsId.notifier).state =
          _currentAgentProfile.get('mlsId');
    }
  }
```

This is the globalProvider:

```
final globalProvider = StateNotifierProvider<GlobalsNotifier, Globals>(
    (ref) => GlobalsNotifier(Globals(
        currentUid: '',
        currentUEmail: '',
        userDocumentId: '',
        companyId: '',
        mlsId: '',
        currentTrxnId: '',
        currentCompanyName: '',
        currentCompanyState: '',
        currentUserId: '',
        currentUserName: '',
        currentUserState: '',
        selectedCompany: '',
        selectedState: '',
        selectedTrxnState: '',
        selectedUser: '',
        selectedUserState: '',
        targetScreen: '',
        newCompany: true,
        newEvent: true,
        newTrxn: true,
        newUser: true)));
```

What am I doing wrong that keeps me from being able to use the update method to update the state?

Thanks

Comment: The literature is rushing to catch up with Remi's prolific development.  In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Comment: Thanks. I thought I was using the newer features. Back to the drawing board.